# the number of binary strings at the same distance from other vertices with some condition

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Let $d(v,w)$ denote the Hamming distance of binary strings $v$ and $w$ of the same length. Given binary strings $x_1,\dots,x_k$ of length $n$ such that $d(x_i,x_j)=2\alpha$ for $i\neq j$, how many strings $x$ are there such that $d(x,x_i)=l$ for $i=1,\dots,k$? I can count the number of such strings for the case $k=2$. I am considering the general case $k\geq 3$. I wonder if this kind of question is well-known so that there have already been results.

--Edit---

(Case $k=2$)
WLOG, $x_1=0\dots 0$ and $x_2=0\dots01\dots 1$ where $1$ appears $2\alpha$ times in $x_2$. If $d(x,x_1)=i$, then $x$ must contain $i$ ones. Denote by $S_i(\{x_1,x_2\})$ the set of all binary strings at the same distance $i$ from $x_1$ and $x_2$. It can be checked that $|S_i(\{x_1,x_2\})|=\binom{2\alpha}{\alpha}\binom{n-2\alpha}{i-\alpha}$ for $i=\alpha,\dots, n-\alpha$.

Comment: Could you share the number of vertices you can count for $k=2$ and $k=3$?

Comment: I've written what I've done for the case $k=2$. For $k=3$, I found something I got wrong. So, I am still considering that case.

Comment: Does $i$ have some known relation with $l$?

Comment: I edited the condition again.

Comment: In case it might be useful, I made a [program](https://onlinegdb.com/H1HRuG83w) for an exhaustive test of all sequences which produces a table of $n,k,\alpha$, $l$ (=$i$) and the number of vertices $v$. The only thing I can get is that for $k=3$ and $\alpha=2$ it should be $|S_i(\{x_1,x_2\})|=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2\alpha}{\alpha}\binom{n-2\alpha}{i-\alpha}$. For $k=3$ and $\alpha=2$ it seems we need division by $6$ (instead of $2$) and then an addition of some $6m$ depending on $l$. Note that for $k\ge4$ the result seems not to depend only on $k,\alpha,l$ (the program prints the differences).

Comment: Let $k=3$ and $\alpha=3$. We may assume that $x_1=0\dots 0$, $x_2=0\dots01$, and $x_3=0\dots010$. Suppose that $d(x,x_j)=i$ for $j=1,2,3$. To count the our desired number, two cases can be considered: 1. x contains a 1 at the last position (contd)

Comment: 2. $x$ does not contains a 1 at the last position. Considering two cases, for the former, we have $\binom{n-3}{i-1}$ for $1\leq i\leq n-2$, and for the latter, $\binom{n-3}{i-2}$ for $2\leq i\leq n-1$. Hence, by Pascal's identity, $\binom{n-2}{i-1}$.

Comment: I think we need to consider $S_i(\{x_1,x_2,x_3\})$.

Comment: I wrote $|S_i(\{x_1,x_2\})|=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2\alpha}{\alpha}\binom{n-2\alpha}{i-\alpha}$ for a mistake, I meant $|S_i(\{x_1,x_2,x_3\})|=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2\alpha}{\alpha}\binom{n-2\alpha}{i-\alpha}$ for $k=3$ and $\alpha=1$. $\alpha=2$ was also wrong there, I meant $k=3$ and $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Not sure if you're considering the condition that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are mutually at the same distance. There do not exist three binary strings such that they are mutually at distance $1$.

Comment: Not $1$, you required the mutual distance be $2\alpha$, so in that case $2\alpha=2$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad! Then, your formula and mine are the same as $\binom{n-2}{i-1}$. I wonder if your program is telling that for $\alpha\geq 2$, your formula holds.

Comment: No, for $k=3$ and $α=2$ it seems we need division by $6$ (instead of $2$) and then an addition of some $6m$ depending on $l$. Note that for $k≥4$ the result seems not to depend only on $k,α,l$ (the program prints when same $(k,α,l)$ give different counts). You can run the program online at the link above.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!